# iTunes Connect CFBundleShortVersionShort must contain a higher version

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, cocoapods

Today Xcode is giving me problems when attempting to upload a build to iTunes connect. It's giving me the following errors:

[image]

What's very strange is my application's `CFBundleVersionShortVersionString` is `2.0.0`. I uploaded a build to TestFlight yesterday and it worked just fine. Then I did a search for `CFBundleVersionShortVersionString`, and I found a `1.0.0` and `0.5.1`, but they were in the `info.plist` in the Pods. Why is this error all of a sudden appearing? I know I'm not supposed to change anything in the Pods. Has anyone come across this issue and if so how can you fix this?

Comment: I am seeing this exact same thing. Started seeing it sometime this afternoon (uploaded this morning with no issues). I'm going to assume its a bug on Apple's part but I hope some can come up with some fix soon.

Comment: I'm seeing this too.  I right-clicked the archive, viewed it in the Finder, and see that there are some third party library bundles containing info.plist files.   The error message is referencing version numbers from those files.  I believe this is an iTunes Connect bug that cropped up earlier today (Back to the Future day).

Comment: Having the same issue here as well.

Comment: I tried using Application Loader for shits and giggles.  I can confirm that it didn't work either.

Comment: Was on the phone with Apple, we tried to upload a version while on shared screen and got the same error. They are not sure of what's causing it. So, there it is. My guess is that it has nothing to do with the version format, but the iTunesConnect servers again.

Comment: Deja vu from iTunes Connect post Xcode 7. Test it in production!

Comment: Just has this warning again trying to upload 3.4 after 3.22. The error mentioned something about info.plist with a version 2.12. I could not find the number '2.12' in any of the plists... No CocoaPods. Looks like an issue with x.yy to x.y format? Apparently there's some kind of a real number calculated from the version string. It'd be great if Apple could share that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there was an issue created for this same issue in CocoaPods - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4421

[blixt](https://github.com/blixt) mentions...

> I think it's the iTunes Connect servers entirely, and not Xcode 7.0
>   nor Xcode 7.1. This issue appears to have started around 10 am PDT. It
>   is definitely a bug, and we fixed it by bumping our dependency's
>   Info.plist CFBundleShortVersionString up to the same version as our
>   app, and voila – iTunes Connect accepted the bundle.

This is an annoying fix but it seems like fixing the individual Info.plist files short version (that your dependencies may have) up to your app version should get you passed this error for now. This is definitely not a long term solution though.